# Maintain an unordered_map but at the same time need the lowest of it's mapped values at every step

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I have an `unordered_map<int, int>` which is updated at every step of a `for` loop. But at the end of the loop, I also need the lowest of the mapped values. Traversing it to find the minimum in `O(n)` is too slow. I know there exists MultiIndex container in boost but I can't use boost. What is the simplest way it can be done using only STL?

Question:

> Given an array A of positive integers, call a (contiguous, not
> necessarily distinct) subarray of A good if the number of different
> integers in that subarray is exactly K.
>
> (For example, [1,2,3,1,2] has 3 different integers: 1, 2, and 3.)
>
> Return the number of good subarrays of A.

My code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int subarraysWithKDistinct(vector<int>& A, int K) {
        int left, right;
        unordered_map<int, int> M;

        for (left = right = 0; right < A.size() && M.size() < K; ++right)
            M[A[right]] = right;
        if (right == A.size())
            return 0;

        int smallest, count;
        smallest = numeric_limits<int>::max();
        for (auto p : M)
            smallest = min(smallest, p.second);
        count = smallest - left + 1;
        for (; right < A.size(); ++right)
        {
            M[A[right]] = right;
            while (M.size() > K)
            {
                if (M[A[left]] == left)
                    M.erase(A[left]);
                ++left;
            }
            smallest = numeric_limits<int>::max();
            for (auto p : M)
                smallest = min(smallest, p.second);
            count += smallest - left + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

Link to the question: https://leetcode.com/problems/subarrays-with-k-different-integers/

Comment: You are asking for two contradictory things. You want your map to be unordered, and at the same time you want fast minimal element, which implies ordering.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I mean of the <key, value> pairs, I need minimum of the "value" of them all.

Comment: Hmm. It isn't quite clear why you need this. If you are mapping a subarray with bounds `(left, right)`, then the lowest value stored in the map is `left`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. the unordered_map saves the last index at which the element `Ai` occurs. I need the lowest of these indices which is required to update count.

Comment: Then perhaps you should be saving all indices instead of the last one. Or just the count of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n)` is not slow, in fact it is the theoretically fastest possible way to find the minimum, as it's obviously not possible to find the minimum of n items without actually considering each of them.

You could update the minimum **during** the loop, which is trivial if the loop only adds new items to the map but becomes much harder if the loop may change existing items (and may increase the value of the until-then minimum item!), but ultimately, this also adds O(n) amount of work, or more, so complexity-wise, it's not different from doing an extra loop at the end (obviously, the constant can be different - the extra loop may be slower than reusing the original loop, but the complexity is the same).

As you said, there are data structures that make it more efficient (O(log n) or even O(1)) to retrieve the minimum item, but at the cost of increased complexity to maintain this data structure during insertion. These data structures only make sense if you frequently need to check the minimum item while inserting or changing items - not if you only need to know the minimum only at the end of the loop, as you described.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It seems you misunderstood my question as I didn't describe it right. I need the lowest mapped value at the end of each iteration of the loop. Also, the unordered_map can be updated in 3 ways: insert, modify and delete. So I can't maintain the lowest value in a variable and update it at each iteration. Also O(n) is slow for the question I'm solving. I'll add the question and my code (which is giving TLE) above.

Comment: Your question asked about finding the minimum at the *end* of the loop, and that's what I answered... ☹️

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple class to make it work although it's far from perfect, it's good enough for the above linked question.

```
class BiMap
{
public:
    void insert(int key, int value)
    {
        auto itr = M.find(key);
        if (itr == M.cend())
            M.emplace(key, S.insert(value).first);
        else
        {
            S.erase(itr->second);
            M[key] = S.insert(value).first;
        }
    }

    void erase(int key)
    {
        auto itr = M.find(key);
        S.erase(itr->second);
        M.erase(itr);
    }

    int operator[] (int key)
    {
        return *M.find(key)->second;
    }

    int size()
    {
        return M.size();
    }

    int minimum()
    {
        return *S.cbegin();
    }

private:
    unordered_map<int, set<int>::const_iterator> M;
    set<int> S;
};

class Solution {
public:
    int subarraysWithKDistinct(vector<int>& A, int K) {
        int left, right;
        BiMap M;

        for (left = right = 0; right < A.size() && M.size() < K; ++right)
            M.insert(A[right], right);
        if (right == A.size())
            return 0;

        int count = M.minimum() - left + 1;
        for (; right < A.size(); ++right)
        {
            M.insert(A[right], right);
            while (M.size() > K)
            {
                if (M[A[left]] == left)
                    M.erase(A[left]);
                ++left;
            }
            count += M.minimum() - left + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```